# Keeping Web.xml in a migrated application from struts2 application to Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, struts2, web.xml

So, I'm trying to migrate a simple struts2 application into spring boot, and I already achieved that by registring the StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter as a bean in my Application.java

The problem is that my client wants to migrate a web application from JAVA EE to Spring boot while keeping web.xml because it has many servlets, filters and listeners, and he doesnt want to register them as beans.

So I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to use web.xml configuration in a spring boot application, I have already spent two days googling about that but still no luck..

Comment: spring boot allows java based config only

Comment: Can't we implement somehow these java config to call and use web.xml ?

Comment: You can import spring xml configuration to java configuration class but couldn't web xml.

Comment: so,to add servlets and filters to my springboot app i'll have to convert all my web.xml to springboot beans?

Comment: Yes .. You need to convert all the functionalities in your servlet to spring controllers and all filters to interceptors.

Comment: Could you pleasse guide me to convert my Struts2 bean filter from java to use it in Spring beans XML file ?
Here is the bean that I have in the main class:
 @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter struts = new StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter();
        registrationBean.setFilter(struts);
        registrationBean.setOrder(1);
        return registrationBean;
    }

also I want do the same with some other filters and listeners